# How to access html elements in ext js panel

Tags: html, extjs

my code:

```
var panel2 = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'myPane1',
    html: "<div style='width:100%;background-color:pink'>" +"<div style='width:49%;border:1px solid blue;float:left' >" + "<input type='text' value='second one' style='width:95%;'></input></div><div id='checkmy_Id' style='width:49%;border:1px solid black;float:left' >" + myVal + "</div></div>" ,
    listeners: {
        render: function (panel2) {
            alert('panel render..');
            //console.log(document.getElementById('checkmy_Id').innerHTML);
        }
    }
});
```

How to append values to the `div` with the `id` of `checkmy_Id`. It gives me an error: `innerHTML is null.`
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
 render: function (panel2) {
      //innerHTML
      console.log(panel2.body.dom.innerHTML);
      //To get HTMLElement
      console.log(Ext.query("#checkmy_Id"));
 }
```